# Limit Visual Studio's edit area to display just one function or method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Years ago, when I worked in VB 6, I could make the editor window display only the function/method that I was working on -- I miss that.

Is there a way, an add-in, or a hack, that would allow me to do the same thing now?

Thanks!!

Comment: The only way I can think of that would allow you to manage your editor is to collapse functions or make liberal use of regions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible by official pathways. However, there are many plugins that allow you to quickly jump to a function/method. I would suggest a few of the following:

- There is a "select member" drop down list at the top-right
- [CodeMaid](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496) has a "spade" window that shows you all items in a file
- If you are willing to spend money, [VS10x Code Map v2](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1c54d1bd-d898-4705-903f-fa4a319b50f2) is a good option

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that this functionality was removed. And that there is no way around it, perhaps you could look into making your own plugin for Visual Studios?

Comment: I would make a plugin if I knew how but am not at that point yet.  That is why I am asking if anyone knows of one that does this.  It is a shame that this has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would implement my class into partial classes, and move my stable code to one of them, focus my code implementation in one of the classes:

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public void StableFunction()
    {
    }
}

public partial class Employee
{
    public void UnStableFunction()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a 77 project solution with innumerable classes worked on by many developers.  I can't change any of that at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently released (commercial) [Task Canvas](https://vlasovstudio.com/task-canvas/) extension for Visual Studio 2015 that lets you choose methods or code selections to work on.