# Single-Procedure View in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio

### Duplicates

This is a sort-a duplicate of two ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073271/limit-visual-studios-edit-area-to-display-just-one-function-or-method), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436156/limit-vb-net-ide-to-show-one-procedure-or-function-at-a-time?lq=1)) questions. However, the accepted answers do not really answer the question.

### Problem

I want to display only one function/procedure at once. Those of you who used VS6 might remember this. I need this to improve editing performance on very large source files. I do *not* need this to jump to the function (that is already a default feature in all VS versions).

The answers in the other questions all suggest plug-ins etc. that solve another problem (jump to header), and state that this is no longer available in VS.

### Question

As this is no longer a feature in VS, is there any possible way to do this (explicitly displaying only one function)? Disabling syntax highlighting for performance is not an option.

**Edit**

Previously, the question included VS15, however, as I just found out, this is not an option.

Comment: "I need this to improve editing performance on very large source files" - then you are likely trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: I would split the file up, but since this is not my decision to make, I can't.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Code Connect](http://codeconnect.io/) extension that lets you navigate code one function at a time.

Comment: That is useful, but as it turns out, I'm not allowed to upgrade the environment to VS15 so I have to find some kind of solution for VS13.

Comment: Code Connect supports VS 2013: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c0c2ad47-957c-4e07-89fc-20996595b6dd

Comment: When installing with VS13 Ultimate, it aborts saying the Version is incompatible. I'll report this to them.